# how to get the GeoLocation of user and get distance - django

Tags: django, geolocation

i am googling for an hour and not coming to something good. my goal is to get the user's location during search and show the distance to the place that the user is looking for. i want to do this in django/python

i am asking this question just to clarify my thoughts and to get some guidance. my thoughts till now are these:

1. get the IP of user. and thru this ip, get the city,country, even street, is it possible to do that accurate track?
2. take the address of each cafe's in the search result and ask Google for calculation of distance. (dont know other way, any ideas?)
3. show the distance (e.g: 3km from here)

i am expecting some guidance for useful API's as an answer and answers to my small question in my steps.

thanks a lot

Comment: You can't do anything client-side? If it's web-based, with HTML5 you can locate a user's [position](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp). If it's a mobile device there probably is a way to get location. For question 2 you really should get the places' latitude and longitude and see [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for distance calculation.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks, is it possible on client-side?

Comment: what part? You don't provide any context in your question so I don't really understand what is your problem. You write about "the search result" and I don't know where it comes from, whether it's client-side or server-side. All I know is that to calculate a distance, you need too pair of latitude/longitude and one mathematical formula - and I can't think of any language that could _not_ implement that formula.

Comment: @Arthur, never mind, i found the answer from your comments :D. thanks dude